# Array variables throw error in Java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
//call for input
System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] num = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
int val = in.nextInt();
num[i] = val;
}

System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums());
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums());

}

public static int sumNums()
{  
return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public static int reverseNums()
{
return num[2] + num[1] + num[0]; 
}  

}
```

Why do the 'num' variables in my two methods below throw an error? Netbeans says cannot find symbol. I tried passing 'int[] num' but it just throws more errors

Comment: Scope of num variable is in main ethod only.either pass it as an arguement or make it global. And please refer to java tutorials.Also use google for looking at the root cause of your errors.

Comment: No one is idle here.Please accept the answers otherwise don't raise questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope of num variable is in main method only.either pass it as an argument or make it global. And please refer to java tutorials.

> **WITH NUM AS ARGUEMENT**

```
package com;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class WorkSheet_1  {
    //static int[] num = new int[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //call for input
        System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        int val = in.nextInt();
        num[i] = val;
        }

        System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums(num));
        System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums(num));

    }



public static int sumNums(int[] num)
{  
    return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public static int reverseNums(int[] num)
{
    return num[2] + num[1] + num[0]; 
}  

}
```

> **WITH NUM AS GLOBAL(STATIC)**

```
package com;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class WorkSheet_1  {
    static int[] num = new int[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //call for input
        System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        int val = in.nextInt();
        num[i] = val;
        }

        System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums());
        System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums());

    }



public static int sumNums()
{  
    return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public static int reverseNums()
{
    return num[2] + num[1] + num[0]; 
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `int[] num` is defined only in the main function but not in other your functions and it's not a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `num` variable is upto `main()` method only. you have to declare it `public static` in class to be able to use from function

Second way is to pass the array as a parameter in function.

Answer (score 0):

Cause the `int[] num` is not visible to the `sumNums()` and `reverseNums()` methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
...

System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums(num));

...

}

public static int sumNums(int[] num)
{  
return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}
```

Comment: After passint 'int[]num' i get 'cannot be applied to given types'

Comment: Strange, it compiles and works with on my ide. Could you pass the whole code that gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

Either you make int[] num class variable or pass int[] num as argument to methods and change method signature.

```
static int[] num = new int[3];
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
//call for input
System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
int val = in.nextInt();
num[i] = val;
}

System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums());
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums());

}

public static int sumNums()
{  
return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public static int reverseNums()
{
return num[2] + num[1] + num[0]; 
} 

}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
//call for input
System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] num = new int[3];
for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
int val = in.nextInt();
num[i] = val;
}

System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums(num));
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums(num));

}

public static int sumNums(in[] num)
{  
return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public static int reverseNums(int[] num)
{
return num[2] + num[1] + num[0]; 
}  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `static` `method` may only use the `static` `variables` of the same class. In your case you used the variable which was not a `static variable`. You may write something like this:

```
int[] num = new int[3];
public static void main(...) {
    //the code you want
    sumMums(num);
}

public static int sumNums(in[] num) {  
   return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}
```